# How to check if a linear code is a polynomial code

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose I have a linear code defined by a generator matrix or parity check matrix.
Are there algorithms to check if the code is a polynomial code? it doesn't have to be a
cyclic code, jut polynomial one.

Comment: define polynomial code

Comment: wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code#:~:text=In%20coding%20theory%2C%20a%20polynomial,%2C%20called%20the%20generator%20polynomial).

Comment: I outlined the check for cyclic codes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3998436/11619). It seems to me that the cyclic case is simpler than the polynomial case. In the polynomial case I think that you must check that the gcd of the rows is a code word. The structure theory of cyclic codes make that unnecessary in that richer case. That stands to reason is the universe of polynomial codes is much larger than that of cyclic codes. And, possibly more importantly, doesn't have as rigid a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the naive way would be decompose each code word into prime factors and check if the $\gcd$ can generate the given code. I do not know if there is a better/efficient algorithm.

Comment: This might be good enough...maybe checking only the generator matrix is enough instead of all codewords

Comment: If the code is long, decomposing the rows of the generator matrix into prime factors may be unpleasant. Calculating the gcd with Euclid's algorithm on the other hand :-)

Comment: And, yes, it suffices to calculate the gcd of the rows of a generator matrix, and then check that the shifted versions of the gcd generate the same code.